# Как вывести значения

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord-api

Этот система левла,когда пользователя пишет в discord сообщения он дедктит сообщения и записывает новые данные в users.json.
Я пытался вывести данные в чат но всё время возникали какие либо проблемы,нормально контактировать с переменными не получается все время какая нибудь ошибка.
Скорей всего это можно сделать очень просто но не достаточно опытен в этом 
так что прошу вас скинуть пример вывода опыта и уровень в чат.

```
import discord
import json
import os
import random
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import datetime
import time
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio
import base64
from threading import Timer
import random
import sqlite3

now = datetime.datetime.now()  # Для времени
timein = 0
timeinfo = "null"
#buka = 0
#experience = None
#lvl_start = None
#resultinfo = base64.b64decode(code)
#textinfo = resultinfo.decode('utf-8')
#print(textinfo)

Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\ZederBreys\Desktop\Lisa poject\Level System')


@Bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Загрузочка')
    print("Имя", Bot.user.name)
    print("Клиент id", Bot.user.id)
    print('Всё Готово')
    print("Начало работы", now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"))


@Bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    await update_data(users, member)

    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)


@Bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    await update_data(users, message.author)
    await add_experience(users, message.author, random.randint(0, 3))
    await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)
    #await level_info(users, message.author, message.channel)

    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
    await Bot.process_commands(message)


async def update_data(users, user):
    if not user.id in users:
        users[user.id] = {}
        users[user.id]['experience'] = 0
        users[user.id]['level'] = 1
async def add_experience(users, user, exp):
    users[user.id]['experience'] += exp


async def level_info(users, user, channel):
    experience = users[user.id]['experience']
    lvl_start = users[user.id]['level']
    await Bot.say(experience, lvl_start)

async def level_up(users, user, channel):
    experience = users[user.id]['experience']   # Перменная experience = exp пользователя
    lvl_start = users[user.id]['level']  # lvl_start обозначает Лвл сейчашний
    print(users)
    print(user)
    print(channel)
    lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))  # lvl_end Лвл сейчашний


    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
        await Bot.send_message(channel, '{} Твой уровень повышен до {}'.format(user.mention, lvl_end))
        users[user.id]['level'] = lvl_end



    Bot.run('token')
```